# Cython "Cannot assign default value to fields in cdef classes, structs or unions"

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I am making my first attempt at porting Python code to Cython. I only have very limited experience with C. I am trying to make a relatively simple class that stores multidimensional arrays. For the purpose of this question, let's leave it to a single one-dimensional array of length 1 for the attribute time. Currently, I am recieving the error:

```
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] time = np.empty([1], dtype=np.int64)
                                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------
data.pyx:22:40: Cannot assign default value to fields in cdef classes, structs or unions
```

Here are the most relevant files.

data.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


cdef extern from "data_extern.h":

    cppclass _Data "Data":

        np.int64_t time64[1]
        double x_coord, y_coord, z_coord
        _Data(np.int64_t *time, double x, double y, double z)


cdef class Data:

    cdef _Data *thisptr
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] time = np.empty([1], dtype=np.int64)

    def __cinit__(self, np.int64_t time[1], x, y, z):
        self.thisptr = new _Data(&time[0], x, y, z)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
```

data_extern.h

```
#ifndef DATA_EXTERN_H
#define DATA_EXTERN_H

class Data {
    public:
        signed long long time64[1];
        double x_coord, y_coord, z_coord;
        Data();
        Data(signed long long time[1], double x, double y, double z;
        ~Data();
};

#endif
```

data_extern.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "data_extern.h"

Data::Data () {}

// Overloaded constructor
Data::Data (signed long long time[1], double x, double y, double z {
    this->time64 = time[0];
    this->x_coord = x;
    this->y_coord = y;
    this->z_coord = z;
}

// Destructor
Data::~Data () {}
```

I recognize there could be multiple problems with my code, but if someone could provide an explanation for the error message it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as stated in the error message: you cannot set a default value for a cdef class's C-level properties. You can get around this by setting the value in the `__cinit__` constructor as follows:

```
cdef class Data:
    cdef _Data *thisptr
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] time

    def __cinit__(self, np.int64_t time[1], x, y, z):
        self.thisptr = new _Data(&time[0], x, y, z)
        self.time = np.empty([1], dtype=np.int64)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
```

As a heads-up though, the whole np.ndarray syntax is rather out of date. Unless you are dead-set on using numpy types (which seem to be unnecessary in your code since you are interfacing with a c++ library of some sort), you can use the more modern [typed memoryview](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) syntax. You could import the sized integer types using `from libc.stdint cimport *` to use those instead of the numpy ones.

Comment: Yes. This indeed got me past the default value error. I will try the memoryview syntax instead. Thanks!

Comment: I've made an alternate solution with a memoryview here, though it is inconsequentially using an array of longs instead of long longs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180703/cython-cannot-take-address-of-memoryview-slice