# Cython "Cannot take address of memoryview slice"

Tags: python, c++, arrays, cython, memoryview

I am having trouble creating a simple class in Cython. There is little documentation related to handling memoryviews for arrays in C++ wrappers. I want to create a data class with time, x, y, and z attributes. I need these attributes to be arrays, which will ultimately be callable in Python. I previously had this working using numpy types, but I would like to do this properly using memoryviews. My background is not strong in C++. For now, I am only trying to get the time attribute working with a single-element 1D array. When I try to build my extensions I get the following error:

```
        self.c_data = new _Data(&date[1], x, y, z)
                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------


data.pyx:18:32: Cannot take address of memoryview slice
```

If I can't take the address of a memoryview slice, how do I initialize my class attributes? Here is the relevant code.

data.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
from . cimport Data


cdef class Data:

    cdef _Data *c_data
    cdef long[::1] date

    def __cinit__(self, long[::1] *date, x, y, z):


        self.c_data = new _Data(&date[1], *date, x, y, z)
        self.date = cvarray(shape=(1), itemsize=sizeof(long), format="i")


    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_data
```

data.pxd

```
cdef extern from "data extern.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "data extern.h":

    cppclass _Data "Data":

        long date[1]
        double x, y, z
        Data() except +
        _Data(long[:], double, double, double) except +
```

data_extern.h

```
#ifndef DATA_EXTERN_H
#define DATA_EXTERN_H

class Data {
    public:
        long date[1];
        double x, y, z;
        Data();
        Data(long date[1], double x, double y, double z);
        ~Data();

};

#endif
```

data_extern.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "data extern.h"

// Default constructor
Data::Data () {}

// Overloaded constructor
Data::Data (long date[1], double x, double y, double z) {
    this->date = date[0];
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}

// Destructor
Data::~Data () {}
```

There are likely other issues with my code. If anybody has any insights on how I can create a class that is callable from python and makes use of cython memoryviews, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you had mentioned it in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60159909/2588654) as an assumption: do you intend to keep the length of the `date` parameter hardcoded to an array of a single `long`, or are you trying to support an arbitrary length array? If you were using a `long *` as you do in the constructor in your c++ code, do you know the number of items that said `long *` points to?

Comment: Will write a more cohesive answer tomorrow when less tired, but since your @property functions are just simple variable getters and setters, you can look at declaring the properties in your `cdef class Date` as `public` (if you want them not modifiable from the python side but still exposed, you can look at `readonly` instead).

Comment: Thanks for your help. For date it will likely be a length 1 array, but I'd like to have the option of it being expandable. For the remaining arrays,  they will all be dynamic 3D or 4D arrays (or vectors of vectors). I would like them modifiable from the Python side, so I will look into setting them as public.

Comment: I guess I am a bit more confused now. Are `x, y, z` representing the dimensions of an array? If so, and you know the number of directions, you can create a multidimensional typed memoryview like `long[:, :, ::1]` and extract the dimensions from the passed in memoryview object. It would be really helpful to see how the c++ `Data` class would be instantiated on the c++ side, since I don't see where the memory is allocated for any arrays.

Comment: So no. x, y, and z would actually be 3 dimensional arrays each (minimally). My actual code has u, v, and w which represent velocities in a 3D grid. I was just trying  to simplify things in my example, and only consider time in one dimension for my question. But yes, my goal is to ultimately have multidimensional arrays for each of these variables. My hope is that I could instantiate the 3D arrays on the C++ side, but have the option of accessing them from Python if I choose. So my arrays would be three dimensional arrays of u, v, w, with the dimensions x, y, z (minimally, maybe a time dim).

Comment: The arrays would be passed from a netcdf file to the C++ arrays ideally, with a C++ class instance holding all of the 3D arrays so I can perform further actions on them such as interpolation.

Comment: Ok that is pretty helpful! If you have the actual c++ header description for the properties of the real Data class with u, v, and w, then I would not mind addressing that directly.

Comment: I only ask because it then might be possible to identify a "packed struct" to use as the type of the memoryview (something like a numpy record array).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207812/discussion-between-codesurgeon-and-user14241).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I quite understand what I've done, but after going back to the original guidance I was following, I was able to get it to work. The guidance I received was a video from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ukI-NlIzqY and the accompanying slides that can be viewed from https://github.com/kwmsmith/scipy2013-cython-tutorial/blob/master/Cython.pdf.

Here are the relevant files.

data.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef class Data:

    cdef _Data *c_data
    cdef long[::1] date

    def __cinit__(self, long[::1] date, x, y, z):
        self.c_data = new _Data(&date[0], x, y, z)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_data

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.c_data.date
    @date.setter
    def date(self, date):
        self.c_data.date = date

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.c_data.x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.c_data.x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.c_data.y
    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self.c_data.y = y

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.c_data.z
    @z.setter
    def z(self, z):
        self.c_data.z = z
```

data.pxd

```
cdef extern from "data extern.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "data extern.h":

    cppclass _Data "Data":

        long date[1]
        double x, y, z
        Data() except +
        _Data(long*, double, double, double) except +
```

data extern.h

```
#ifndef DATA_EXTERN_H
#define DATA_EXTERN_H

class Data {
    public:
        long *date;
        double x, y, z;
        Data();
        Data(long date[1], double x, double y, double z);
        ~Data();

};

#endif
```

data extern.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "data extern.h"

// Default constructor
Data::Data () {}

// Overloaded constructor
Data::Data (long *date, double x, double y, double z) {
    this->date = &date[0];
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}

// Destructor
Data::~Data () {}
```